# Getting good accuracy but very low precision for classification task on an unbalanced dataset

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I have an unbalanced dataset , where the positive class is about 10,000 entries and the negative class is some 8,00,000 entries. I am trying a simple scikit's LogisticRegression model as a base line model, with class_weight='balanced' (hopefully unbalanced problem should be solved?).

However, I am getting an accuracy score of 0.83, but a precision score of 0.03. What could be the issue? Do I need to handle the unbalanced part separately?

This is my current code:

```
>>> train = []
>>> target = []
>>> len(posList)
... 10214
>>> len(negList)
... 831134
>>> for entry in posList:
...     train.append(entry)
...     target.append(1)
...
>>> for entry in negList:
...     train.append(entry)
...     target.append(-1)
...
>>> train = np.array(train)
>>> target = np.array(target)
>>> 
>>> X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train, target, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
>>> 
>>> model = LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced')
>>> model.fit(X_train, y_train)
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight='balanced', dual=False,
          fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100,
          multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=1, penalty='l2', random_state=None,
          solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
>>> 
>>> predicted = model.predict(X_test)
>>> 
>>> metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, predicted)
0.835596671213
>>> 
>>> metrics.precision_score(y_test, predicted, average='weighted')
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:976: DeprecationWarning: From version 0.18, binary input will not be handled specially when using averaged precision/recall/F-score. Please use average='binary' to report only the positive class performance.
  'positive class performance.', DeprecationWarning)
0.033512518766
```

Comment: `I am getting an accuracy score of 0.83, but a precision score of 0.03. What could be the issue` - It may help you understanding to check what accuracy/precision scores you get when you randomly predict 10000 positive and the rest negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what is going on.

Consider a dummy classifier that would return the majority class for each sample of your data set. For an unbalanced set like yours it seems pretty fair (let's call your positive class *class 1* and the negative one *class 0*). The classifier would have an accuracy of : `831134/(831134+10214.0) = 0.987859958067292`. Yes, **an accuracy of 99%**, but it doesn't give a good representation of your classifier. Instead, we'd better look at its **precision**. So since your data is really unbalanced (ratio `1:80`) the Logistic Regression performs poorly, but as for the dummy classifier, it has a high accuracy.

**Precision** is defined as the ratio of *true positives* and the sum of *true positives* and *false positives*. In other words, it is the proportion of *elements truly belonging to class 1* amongst *all the elements detected as belonging to class 1*.

The accuracy of your LinearRegression classifier is `acc = 0.835596671213`. Thus, their is a difference of accuracy between the dummy classifier and the logistic regression of : `diff = 0.987859958067292 - 0.835596671213 = 0.15226328685429202`. So **15%** of the data has been **misclassified** by the dummy classifier, which corresponds to almost `n_misclass = 0.15*(831134+10214.0)=126202.2` samples. Thus, the Logistic regression classifies **126202** samples as being from *class 1* while they are only  **10214**.

The **precision that Logistic Regression** might then be something like : `prec = 10214/126202.0 = 0.081`.

In your case it seems that it performs less good in terms of accuracy than what we've seen above. But that was roughly to give you a clue about what might be going on.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but in scikit's documentation http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html, they mention that for class_weight='balanced' it handles the unbalanced portion. "The “balanced” mode uses the values of y to automatically adjust weights inversely proportional to class frequencies in the input data as n_samples / (n_classes * np.bincount(y)).
". Shouldn't this solve the above problem?